# Magento funnel in google analytics, place order clicked very high (no counted as success)

Tags: onepage-checkout, google-analytics

we have conversion funnel on checkout in analytics

We see the below in last step

- 11 out of 20 succesful
- place order clicked, but?? did not visit the succes URL

**Question:** now what is? and what is causing the high place order clicked %?

Can this be the people that clicked cancel on the (external) payment page? (but we dont have so many cancellations

Or can it be the people that do the payment, but before the succes url can load they click away?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is often caused by customers who indeed do not return to your success page after paying for the order.

compare these numbers with the page-views on the success page to see if users are indeed not returning to the success page.

Comment: I will check. Is there a way to include it?

Comment: quite difficult, because the visitor is not returning to the success page. With some payment providers however, it is possible to force the redirect to your website. Often called something like 'automatic redirect' or 'skip transaction complete'.

Comment: did you find it?

Comment: no I am not sure it is possible. Also you would not want to count it - because in our case they go to an external (payment) site. They may click cancel or just close the page. But it is strange because I don't see as many cancelled/in progress orders as I would expect

Comment: The problem is probably that people do pay, but do not continue back to your website, so the visit to /checkout/success is not registered. What payment provider are you using? I know for example the MultiSafePay plugin offers the option to skip the 'transaction complete' page and go directly back to your /checkout/success page.

Comment: We are using Dutch equivalent - I think it goes directly to succes page. That is why I find it a little strange - even the request would/should already trigger page load -- but then maybe not in time for Google Analytics load